# Maven is trying to add an inexisting file

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to "mavenize" a java ee project but I have several errors on a repertory :

[image]

The file BoiteTest.java doesn't exist in the repertory but Maven is trying to get it. How can I avoid it please ?

**EDIT 1 :**

In my workspace, I have 4 projects and a parent pom:

> pom.xml
>
> Persyst_1.4.3
>
> persyst_server_ejb_1.4.3
>
> persyst-common_1.4.3
>
> persyst-server-ear_1.4.3

The error is :

\Users\Lison\workspace\persyst_server_ejb_1.4.3\sr`\test\java\fr\inra\grignon\persyst\ejb\module\azote\BoiteTest.java:[272,12] cannot find symbol
symbol : variable TestDataResult
location : class test.java.fr.inra.grignon.persyst.ejb.module.azote.BoiteTest

Comment: Try mvn clean package -DskipTests , if  build success => u have compilation problem at phase test-compile

Comment: @question_maven_com I have the same error than with mvn clean install

Comment: @question_maven_com I did on the source repertory and every build is successful ! Does that mean that all the projects are ok ?

Comment: @question_maven_com Can we speak somewhere else, I have some questions please ?

Comment: @question_maven_com https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94589/maven Please

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml files to the question, particularly if your setting the test source location. (This looks wrong: "Location: class **test** . **java** .fr.inra.....")